# How to call a base class __init__ as self?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I re-initialize the base class using `self.__init__`?

In the following example my goal is to inherit eComm which is a socket derived driver. This handles connect/disconnect. If it disconnects we need to reinitialize it using `__init__`, however it appears to refer to the comDriver when `self.__init__` is called.

How do I properly initialize the superclass to allow for this?

(else: `self.__init__` in connect() is referring to comDriver, not eComm like it should)

The following is a simple case to reproduce the error in Python 3.x

```
class eComm():

    def __init__(self):
        self.s = "example object"
        self.initialized = True                                    
        self.connected = False                                

    def connect(self, IP_ADDRESS, PORT):                
        if self.initialized:                                
            print(IP_ADDRESS, PORT)
        else:                                        
            print("REINITIALIZING")
            self.__init__()                        
        self.connected = True                             

        return(True)

class comDriver(eComm):

    def __init__(self, IP_ADDRESS, PORT):
        self.IP = IP_ADDRESS
        self.PORT = PORT
        super().__init__()
        pass

    def getTemp(self):
        print("EXAMPLE FUNCTION")
        return(1)

x = comDriver("192", 7)

x.connect("161", 6)
x.initialized = False
x.connect("111", 5)
```

Comment: That's probably a bad use of Python's special method `__init__`. You may want to create a separate "initializer" method, and call it from `__init__`.

Comment: "If it disconnects we need to reinitialize it using `__init__`" - that's a bad idea. `__init__` really should only be used to set up new instances. While it's technically possible to call it on already-initialized instances, doing so leads to all kinds of headaches.

Answer (score 2):

IMO you're using the special method `__init__` wrongly. It's meant to initialize a Python object, not anything outside that scope.

With your intention, I recommend that you create a separate initializer function, and call it from `__init__`. Here's an example:

```py
class eComm():
    def __init__(self):
        self.initialize_eComm()

    def initialize_eComm(self):
        self.s = "example object"
        self.initialized = True
        self.connected = False
```

And then you can replace `self.__init__()` with `self.initialize_eComm()` to avoid name conflict in subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

> self.__init__ in connect() is referring to comDriver, not eComm like it should

This doesn't quite hold -- `self` refers to the calling object, which is `comDriver`. If you want to call to the `__init__` method on `eComm` regardless of what classes extend it, you will have to reference in explicitly.

```
eComm.__init__(self)
```

But, the other answers and comments are right that this is not a good use of `__init__`.